# How can i do a query in sql that gives the person o owns more houses?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, sqlite

I have 2 tables, house and clients , a cliente can have many houses but a house only belongs to a client, i need a query that gives me the person that owns more houses , how can i do that ?
I know how to do a Count(*) and a Max but i cant build the right way to give what i want

Tables 
House
Id
Price
Adress
Id_client

Clients
Id
Name

Comment: Use a sub select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following :-

```
SELECT clients.id, clients.name, count(id_client) AS houses_owned FROM house JOIN clients ON id_client = clients.id 
GROUP BY id_client 
ORDER BY count(id_client) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

**However, if a number of clients owned the same number of the most owned houses then only one of them would be returned.**

For example consider the following test example ():-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS house;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS clients;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS house (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, address TEXT, id_client INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS clients (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name);
INSERT INTO clients (name) VALUES ('Fred'),('Mary'),('Tom'),('Jane');
INSERT INTO house (address,id_client) VALUES 
    ('House 1',3),('House 2', 1),('House 3',2),('House 4',1),('House 5',3);
SELECT clients.id, clients.name, count(id_client) AS houses_owned FROM house JOIN clients ON id_client = clients.id 
GROUP BY id_client 
ORDER BY count(id_client) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

The result would be :-

[image]

However, Tom also owns 2 houses, removing the LIMIT 1 clause, results in :-

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! This is just what i needed

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments, this can be done using a sub select.  The sub select will grab all of the clients and how many houses they each have, then order it by the client who has the most houses.  The main select will then grab the first result from this (using the `limit 1`) to find which client has the most houses.

```
select
sub.id,
sub.name,
sub.count
from (
    select clients.id, count(houses.id) as count
    from clients
    inner join houses on
    clients.id = houses.id_client
    group by houses.id_client
    order by count desc
) as sub
limit 1;
```

Comment: You've forgotten to include the **name** column in the sub query. e.g. you could have  `select clients.id, count(houses.id) as count, clients.name`

Answer (score 2):

This query will return **all** owners who have the maximum number of houses owned (i.e. if 3 owners all have 5 houses, and 5 is the maximum number of houses owned by any client, this will return all of them). It joins `clients` to a table of the number of houses each client owns, then compares that number to the maximum number of houses owned by any client (the subquery in the `WHERE` clause):

```
SELECT c.name, h.houses_owned
FROM clients c
JOIN (SELECT id_client, COUNT(*) AS houses_owned 
      FROM houses
      GROUP BY id_client) h
  ON h.id_client = c.id
WHERE h.houses_owned = (SELECT COUNT(*) AS houses_owned 
                        FROM houses
                        GROUP BY id_client
                        ORDER BY houses_owned DESC
                        LIMIT 1)
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2bbf6/12) (thanks @MikeT for the data)